# How to get a job abroad with a PhD Degree but without strong publication lists?

Tags: working-visas, job-hunting

On 25th Sept 2018, 2 days ago, I just officially graduated from doctoral degree program in structural engineering field. However, my phd record is not really outstanding. I mean, I only have two publication, with only one is from good journal.
The thing is I just realized that I am not really good at the research topic I did in my doctoral program, but I could not do much at that time since my phd was funded by my supervisor, so I ended up spending my 4 year doing something I am not into it.

and now I am looking for any opportunity for me to get a job oversea such as in Canada (I have been in love with this country), I am still thinking what kind of job that can fit me with my current state.
I have been also checking for teaching jobs at high school because I think university faculty position eligibility requirements are too high for me.

I have my bachelor degree in civil engineering, master in civil engineering as well in Indonesia, and I got my PhD in engineering in Japan.
I have been thinking so hard where to go, industry, university, or schools

I would really appreciate if anyone can help me find ideas to land me to Canada and settle life there

best regards,
Cindy

Comment: Are you looking for a job in a research institution or a job in 'industry'? The former would probably place a much more significant emphasis on publications than the latter.

Comment: Actually yes I am thinking of any job is fine for me, but as you said, I agree that research institutions require outstanding publication records, and I do not have that

Answer (score 2):

If you want to continue in academia, you should look for post-doc positions. There you will do more research and can bolster your record. That would enable to apply for a beginning academic position like as an assistant professor.

To work as a civil or structural engineer, you would need to become licensed in Canada. Check out [this website](https://engineerscanada.ca/become-an-engineer/for-internationally-trained-engineers).

Part of the licensure process will likely include detailed information about your degree programs (courses taken, etc.) plus exams.